# Mysql Query for fetching records using single Query from three tables

Tags: mysql

We have three table 
table 1- app ( id , name ) 
table 2- appPlayer ( id , name )
table 3- appPlayerSession ( id , appId  , appPlayerId , version)

**my Current query is:**

```
SELECT  (select name from app k where k.id= aps.appId) AS appName,version,appId,count(version) FROM appPlayerSession aps GROUP BY appId,version,appName
```

we need to count the session users for each game with same version, and also woth the object of all users data using single mysql query.

Current Result using my query, but we also need players for each app..

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the mysql-docs related to 'joins': https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html 

You will find the answer, you should use joins.

Comment: you are right try joins but what about count? we need to fetch the all records using single mysql query...

Comment: You can select all the information from app (id, name) join the app player table on the app-id (which I hope is related to the app-user information) , get his name and then you can join the session table based on the player ids. When joining those 3 together each table will get an alias (most likely a single character like appPlayer p) which you can then refer to in your upfront select query. There you can use the count function on any column you joined (e.g. SELECT ... count(s.appPlayerId) ..).

Comment: run one more inner select statement as you run for appid  and add the same into your group by clause.Also do aliasing while writing query as this will decrese overhead while reading quaey

Comment: @Kandy can you please write down the query :D ?

Comment: @Kandy with inner we just got the single entry what if we have more then 1 users for one game of version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you havent given your expected result and on basis of your requirement you can do something this.it may be enhanced as per your requirement.

```
SELECT  (select name from app k where k.id= aps.appId) AS appName,version,appId,(select P.name from appPlayer P where P.id=aps.appPlayerid) as appPlayerName, count(version) FROM appPlayerSession aps GROUP BY appId,version,appName,appPlayerName
```

Also check fiddle as per your requirement created as you havent given any data set and its on my assumption.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30fe4f/1

New Sql as per your new added requirement-

```
select X.appname,X.version,X.appid,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct X.appPlayerName      order by X.appPlayerName) as Users ,
 sum(X.vercount) 
 from (SELECT  (select name from app k where k.id= aps.appId) 
 AS appName,version,appId,
 (select P.name from appPlayer P where P.id=aps.appPlayerid) 
 as appPlayerName, count(version)as vercount
 FROM appPlayerSession aps 
 GROUP BY appId,version,appName,appPlayerName) X
 group by X.appname,X.version,X.appid
```

New fiddle -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13646c/5

Comment: Now please check your answer link , here we have two entries for appId 1 , where we have 2 diff users for same version..

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar can you add data set in third table in my fiddle as per your requirement.

Comment: Already added , please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13646c/1

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar can you add your expected output for same described situation

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar please check new sql as per requirement and also please upvote answer  if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN in sql to connect with multiple tables and fetch result

Below is the format :

```
SELECT t1.col, 
       t3.col 
FROM   table1 
       JOIN table2 
         ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey 
       JOIN table3 
         ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```

In your case :

```
SELECT app.col, 
       appPlayer.col,
     appPlayerSession.col 
FROM   app 
       JOIN appPlayer 
         ON app.id = appPlayer.appId
       JOIN appPlayerSession 
         ON appPlayer.id = appPlayerSession.appPlayerId
```

Hope this is helpful.

One suggestion . It is not a standard to use camelCase for table and column names. snake_case is preferred widely.